# How to give dynamic URL in <router-link> in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using v-for directive to get URL name. However, I am facing difficulty in passing the value obtained from a instance of v-for as URL name.

```
<template>
  <v-list-tile class="pl-5" v-for="choice in choices" :key="choice.name">
    <v-list-title-content>
      <router-link to="'/' + choice.name">
        <v-list-title-title class="white--text headline">
          {{choice.name}}
        </v-list-title-title>
      </router-link>
    </v-list-title-content>
  </v-list-tile>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      choices:[
         name:'A',
         name:'B',
         name:'C',
         name:'D'
      ]    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to bind `to`. Try something like this

```
<router-link :to="'/' + choice.name">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, In order to make any attributes to dynamic, you need to use `v-bind` directive.

> Short-hand property for `v-bind` is `:`

Hence you can use it as below

```
<router-link v-bind:to="'/' + choice.name">
```

With short-hand

```
<router-link :to="'/' + choice.name">
```

> Official v-bind [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the choice name like any other variable property: Use `v-bind:to` or the shorthand form `:to`.

Here are the docs to `v-bind`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

You can also directly bind an object to the `to` directive, passing along the name of the route, so that you need to concat a path. Like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'choice1' }">Link</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example with Data():**

```js
<router-link :to="myURL">My Link</router-link>

export default {
    // ...
    data() {
        return {
            myURL: '/my-page-link'
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Example without data()**

```js
<router-link :to="/my-page-link">My Link</router-link>
```

Note: `v-bind` OR `:` before `to` attribute

Answer (score 0):

one tip:

when using v-bind like:

```
// Box.vue
<router-link id="box" :to="{ path: pathto }">{{ name }}</router-link>
```

don't do the fool thing like me as below:

```
<Box name="Frontend" pathto="/box/frontend" />
<Box />
<Box />
```

then you break down.